# Shifting focus from ListView in android

Tags: android

I have a Button and a List View in my layout. List items have got a selector. When the application starts the button is focussed and the selector is on the first item. What I want is when the button is focussed the selector should not be on any item. When I focus on the List view items,then only the selector should come on the selected item.  Any help????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to the outermost layout of the xml which represents your list view row item.

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

am i clear enough?